# KSQL join out-of-order records and 1:1 relations with multiple updates

Tags: join, apache-kafka, stream, ksqldb

Given a streaming process, in which incoming data is enriched by a producer and an `inner join` between incoming and enricher streams produces an enriched output stream:

```
CREATE STREAM ENRICHED_OUTPUT AS \
SELECT * FROM INCOMING_STREAM A \
INNER JOIN ENRICHER_STREAM B \
WITHIN 7 DAYS ON A.ID = B.ID
```

then

`SELECT * FROM ENRICHED_OUTPUT`

would deliver the following result, *as soon as* key `123` exists in both streams:

```
+------+------+--------+--------+
| A_ID | B_ID | A_DATA | B_DATA |
+------+------+--------+--------+
| 123  | 123  | FOO    | BAR    |
+------+------+--------+--------+
```

The cool thing: If processing of id `123` in the enricher is delayed, the `inner join` would ensure that `ENRICHED_OUTPUT` is delayed until `ENRICHER_STREAM` contains key `123`.

Pretty exactly what I want.

But given `ENRICHER_STREAM` contains two entries for key `123` in the last 7 days with values BAR and BAZ, `ENRICHED_OUTPUT` would produce two rows for each incoming key `123`:

```
+------+------+--------+--------+
| A_ID | B_ID | A_DATA | B_DATA |
+------+------+--------+--------+
| 123  | 123  | FOO    | BAR    |
+------+------+--------+--------+
| 123  | 123  | FOO    | BAZ    |
+------+------+--------+--------+
```

pretty exactly not what I want.

I understand that joining to a table `ENRICHER_TABLE` would solve the 1:1 join correctly and deliver the latest state of key `123`:

```
+------+------+--------+--------+
| A_ID | B_ID | A_DATA | B_DATA |
+------+------+--------+--------+
| 123  | 123  | FOO    | BAZ    |
+------+------+--------+--------+
```

Which again is pretty much what I want.

The issue with this approach is that stream-table joins do not update when the table updates and `ENRICHED_OUTPUT` would skip all incoming events until `ENRICHER_TABLE` has key `123`

Again, this is not what I want.

So my question is:

What would be a clean approach to ensure 1:1 relations with out-of-order records and multiple updates on a key within a time-window?

Comment: Maybe a Table-Table join does what you want?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not - afaik those do not update once one side of the join receives new data.

Comment: They do. Compare: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Join+Semantics#KafkaStreamsJoinSemantics-KTable-KTableJoin

Comment: Hm, no... “KTable input record updates the current KTable view but does never yield any result record”. Only Stream-Stream yield results if either side of the join updates. Also compare “KStream-KTable joins are always non-windowed joins. They allow you to perform table lookups against a KTable (changelog stream) upon receiving a new record from the KStream (record stream).” (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#streams-developer-guide-dsl-joins). I guess I need to split the process, perform lookups on the table and retry if not present. Thanks :)

Comment: Your first quote if from KStream-KTable join, not KTable-KTable join -- you are right, that KTable-KTable joins are non-windowed thought.